# Sharepoint/MS Lists Person field lookup

Tags: sharepoint, lookup

In one List for Process Owners I have a title (text field) and person (person field).

[image]

In another list I have processes, where there should be an owner for each.  This should be a drop down option as a lookup field to choose one of the roles as per the first table.  Once this is chosen, the name of the person in that role should automatically populate.

What I have is this, with the red area what I'm missing and wish to have.

[image: ![enter image description here]

It is designed in this way so that if a person changes roles, I just need to update the Process Owners table rather than every single process related to that person.

As per above, I have successfully added the lookup field for role, however I cannot get the Person field to show at all.

When reviewing the Process Owner Role lookup field, I am expecting to see 'Person in role' as an available field to add so that when a role is selected, the person associated to the role will automatically populate.

[image]

I looked up other queries and it seems people field may not be an available option and coding may be required, but couldn't find one to match what I am doing if anybody could please assist.  I am not a coder so please go easy :D

Thanks

Comment: Lookup fields do not support extending people columns in lookup settings - this is a limitation by default. So yes, you will have to use the custom solution like Power Apps or Power automate for this.